# Problemas con ejs

Tags: nodejs, ejs

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en NodeJS y necesito instalar el motor de vistas EJS, pero a la hora de instalarlo me sale el siguiente error:

"npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 139
npm ERR! ejs@3.1.3 postinstall: `node --harmony ./postinstall.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 139
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ejs@3.1.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above."

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final lo he podido resolver por mí mismo. Por si a alguien le pasa lo mismo que me ha pasado a mí, la solución es instalar la versión 2.6.1 de EJS de la siguiente forma:

```
mpm i ejs@2.6.1
```